# Django: L10N and en-IN

Tags: python, django

I googled a lot to find solution for my problem related to Django's **L10N** settings for `en-IN` and found nothing satisfying which works. So, finally get back here to friends.

I'm struggling to format currency as Indian number formatting standard. Which follows `NUMBER_GROUPING = (3, 2, 0)` and `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-IN'`.

My current configurations of `settings.py` file is:

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-IN'
USE_I18N = False
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
NUMBER_GROUPING = (3, 2, 0)
```

Also tried setting:

```py
USE_I18N = True
```

In template file I use:

```html
{% load humanize %}
{# where object.price value is 524300 #}
<p>
{{ object.price }}
<!-- and -->
{{ object.price|intcomma }}
</p>
```

However this outputs:

**524,300** instead **5,24,300**

[image]

> What am I doing wrong, which is stopping Django for follow settings of `LANGUAGE_CODE`, `USE_L10N` and `NUMBER_GROUPING`

#### It works for `hi-IN`

> If I changes `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hi-IN'`, I get expected output of formatted currency as **5,24,300**. But the problem is our site is not in **Hindi** language but in **Indian English** with **Hindi** localization.
>   What a mess :(

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-NUMBER_GROUPING) even showing example for language `en_IN`. Which clearly telling it will format numbers as I expected. But it is not working for me.

Setting `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en_IN'` throws error. Do not accept underscore but hyphen.

My current system locale settings are as below:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Any idea or suggestion will really be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem using Django's custom format files for **L10N**.

I dig deep into docs and found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files), solved my problem.

So, my new revision is here which solved my query even without changing `LANGUAGE_CODE`.

My current `mysite/settings.py` is:

```py
USE_I18N = False
USE_L10N = True

FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = [
    'mysite.formats'
]
```

And tree structure of formats is:

```
./mysite/formats/
|- __init__.py
|- en/
   |- __init__.py
   |- formats.py
```

```py
# formats.py
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
NUMBER_GROUPING = (3, 2, 0)
```

And it works!

Comment: Happy for you. I tried it yesterday but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @Houda It didn't work for me either until I tried setting `USE_I18N = False`—then it worked. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

When "formats" are controlled by templates, the result depends not only on Django settings but also on the system and the browser settings

The best thing to do is to send it as a pre-formated string to the html template :

```
pip install Babel

from babel.numbers import format_currency
format_currency(524300, 'INR', locale='en_IN')
```

Result what ever are Django and system and Browser settings :

```
₹5,24,300.00
```

Comment: How can I suppress "system and the browser settings" and go only with my settings. Because my app will be only is one language and support local localiztion

Comment: I tried with edge; you can select in language settings 'en-IN',  but it was not possible with firefox. I also tried with a custom formats file. I wasn't able to get NUMBER_GROUPING work.

Comment: How's this can be a mess with browser' settings. When I set `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hi-IN'; NUMBER_GROUPING = (3, 2, 0)` in Django's setting then it works. With **en-IN** why it conflicts with browser's language!!!

Comment: Because en is english and hi is hindi; with the same localization . As you can see no matter what you put in your settings; the localisation India doesn't work. you can set in your html diffrent instance : value, value|intcomma, value|localize, value|unlocalize all what you get is 524300 or 524,300 with thousand seperator of your choice. And as interesting exercice try to change browser language and you can see. Can you please tell me where in django setting you can change "locale name"and set it to "en_IN"cause "en-IN" is a langage setting. Don't  foget language settings in your html code too

Comment: When I say browser langage settings I mean supported langages

Comment: Here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-NUMBER_GROUPING it says this can be achieved by configuring `NUMBER_GROUPING`. I did same thing hence it is not working. Setting language `en_IN` throws error "You have provided an invalid value for the LANGUAGE_CODE"

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/#definitions

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py`,

```
USE_L10N = True # or False

FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = [
    'my_project.formats'
]

USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True #this line must be present in settings
```

Create formats.py as in,

```
› my_project/
  › formats/
    › en/
       __init__.py
       formats.py
    __init__.py
```

In `formats.py`,

```
NUMBER_GROUPING = (3, 2, 0)
```

Ref, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/formatting/